# iOS Safari 13.X no longer styling scroll bars

Tags: ios, css, safari

I have a web app that draws lots of overflowed canvases with windows styled scroll bars.

Previously on iOS 12.X this worked fine and we had 17px scroll bars being overlayed, this behaviour still works-on Android Chrome, and all desktop browsers.

Here's a JS fiddle of a "typical" item we have https://jsfiddle.net/wf80rp5g/4/

css for it

```
.VTSOuterDiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  /* This color is also used by WIN_NODE's setCanvasSize method, so if we change this
     then we should update that. */
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgb(205, 205, 205);
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: normal;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background-color: rgb(141, 141, 141);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:active {
  background-color: rgb(141, 141, 141);
}
```

On desktop browser there's scroll bars, on chrome mobile and older safari there's scroll bars, but on 13.X we no longer get stylized scroll bars.

is there any known work arounds for this? the release notes aren't forth coming about this change.

Comment: Are there any updates?

Comment: No sadly not. Funny enough though the code we use to calculate how big a scroll bar is still works and reports size 17, but they do not display.

Comment: Still not working under iOS 14.x too.